# Low voltage cut-off with delay

Tags: transistors, relay, undervoltage

I want to put an accessory on my motorcycle that consumes 40mA even it isn't in use, but I don't want to drain the battery.

I want to put a low voltage cut-off circuit with relay set to 11.6V to protect the battery.

My problem is, when I start the motorcycle, which requires a lot of current, it will cause the voltage to drop up to 10V for at least 1 sec.  The circuit will activate and will turn-off my accessory.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Welcome! How is the cut-off implemented? Can you place a low pass filter in front of it?

Comment: The battery will be pretty well drained by the time the voltage drops low enough to shut it off. Is there possibly a better way to turn it off completely when not in use?

Comment: The devil is in the details so, what we need are the current consumption of your device and the voltage trip point.

Comment: It is a keyless remote so it shouldn't turn-off. I will only use relay, transistor, resistor and flyback diode. Cut-off Voltage is 11.6V so that the battery will not be damage. During ignition, the voltage will drop up to 10V for at least 1 second. The device consume 40mA.

Comment: Aside, consider that Lithium batteries are becoming available for motorcycles.  These are lighter, have slightly higher voltage, and can have much higher current, so less sag when cranking.  I'd recommend one as they are much more robust in general.

Comment: Could I simply put a capacitor to delay the activation?